# Curl using URL-encoded data

Tags: json, url, curl, parameters

Curl is refusing to take PUT request data in the url-encoded form, or any form other than JSON.

I am using the curl command on OS X.

Here is the relevant part of the command that i am running:

`curl <other options> -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlen-coded' --data-urlencode '_id=postcodes-backup-monday'`

Anything i try is met with blank refusal and the following error message:

"{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}"

My response to this is: well of course this is valid JSON - i am sending the data in url-encoded form ...

The command also refuses to parse valid JSON as valid JSON if i try that too.

Answer (score 0):

The data you send is not a JSON.

You should

```
curl <other options> -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlen-coded' \
--data-urlencode '{"_id":"postcodes-backup-monday"}'
```